# Kак реализовать control.RoutePanel с добавлением точки?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Не могу найти в документации свойство, позволяющее включить возможность добавления точек в маршрут. Tак как на картинке:

[image: Как получить реализацию control.RoutePanel с добавлением точки]

Стандартный скрипт:

```
routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
        options: {
            // Добавим заголовок панели.
            showHeader: true,
            title: ''
        }
    }),
```

отрисовывает только выбор двух точек и сброс маршрута.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Панель маршрутизации `RoutePanel` не позволяет добавлять промежуточные точки к маршруту. На скриншоте приведена панель на Яндекс.Картах, которая не предоставляется как стандартный контрол в API.

Маршрут с промежуточными точками и собственную панель вы можете сделать самостоятельно, например через [редактор мультимаршрута](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_edit?from=SO) или задав промежуточные точки в модели мультимаршрута ([пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_driving?from=SO)).

Comment: Спасибо! Эти примеры я видел и разбирал.Редактор мультимаршрута предусматривает статическое указание точек, а мне точки надо получать из RoutePanel (динамически, выбирать на карте).

Comment: @Влад вам понадобится собрать свою панель, потому что в API нет готового контрола с возможностью указывать промежуточные точки. В песочнице есть пример на собственный элемент управления - понадобится сделать свою панель с инпутами и кнопкой "добавить точку".

Comment: Спасибо! Эту задачу я решил! Использовал редактор маршрутов, с пустым массивом referencePoints, редактор строит по карте. Но возникла другая проблема - я сделал кнопку удаления маршрута (прицепил к ней   myMap.geoObjects.remove(multiRoute)) но при нажатии на кнопку маршрут удаляется и перестает работать редактор маршрутов. Требуется перезагрузка страницы что бы редактор опять начал работать.

Comment: Редактор включается на конкретном маршруте. Попробуйте не удалять маршрут, а, например, очищать referencePoints.